# I want to write a shell script that takes commands given in a .txt file and execute them

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I want to write a shell script that takes commands given in a .txt file and execute them.

i have a .txt file with mail commands for multiple users. i want to write a script to invoke and execute the commands given in file. please help

Comment: Please show the mentioned .txt file and what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file contains a list of commands you can just `pipe` it to `bash` or your favorite shell in order to execute them. You can also (better way of doing) redirect the file as stdin of `bash` or your favorite shell.

**INPUT:**

```
$ more commands.txt 
echo abc
echo 123
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ cat commands.txt | bash
abc
123
```

or even better

```
$ bash < commands.txt
abc
123
```

or simply

```
$ bash commands.txt
abc
123
```

or the best (add a shebang at the first line of your commands.txt to point to your favorite shell)

```
$ more commands.txt
#!/bin/bash
echo abc
echo 123
```

run it after giving execution permissions (`chmod u+x commands.txt`)

```
./commands.txt
abc
123
```

Some shebangs that might interest you:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#!/usr/bin/tcl
#!/bin/sed -f
#!/usr/awk -f
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) it worked

Comment: @reshmavishnudev: great! don't hesitate to accept my answer ;-)